# Only show results for occupation table if there is only 1 row

Tags: count

I have 2 tables, `PERSONS` and `OCCUPATION`. I need to find out if the `STATUS` field in the `PERSONS` table shows 'Active' while the `STATUS` field in the `OCCUPATION` table shows 'Terminated'. However, sometimes employees have 2 occupations so there would be 2 rows in the `OCCUPATION` table, one showing 'Active' and the other showing 'Terminated'.

I only want to see records from the PERSONS table where the status = 'Active' and show only if there is only 1 row in the OCCUPATION table that shows 'Terminated'. I need to supress records where one occupation is still active while another one is Terminated.

I am stuck. I got this far:

```
SELECT
OCCUPATION.STATUS,
PERSONS.STATUS,
PERSONS.UPID
FROM OCCUPATION
    INNER JOIN PERSONS
    ON OCCUPATION.PERSONID = PERSONS.QSID
WHERE occupation.STATUS <> PERSONS.STATUS
AND occupation.STATUS = 'Terminated'
```

Can someone please help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I propose something like that:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85a0ab/2

```
SELECT people.* 
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE
people.pstatus = 'Active'
AND people.pid IN (
  SELECT pid
  FROM OCCUPATION 
  WHERE occupation.ostatus = 'Terminated' 
  AND pid NOT IN 
    (SELECT pid FROM OCCUPATION WHERE occupation.ostatus <> 'Terminated')
);
```

So I select `people.id` in `occupations` that are "termninated" and does not appear in the "non terminated" list. Then, I use that list of `people_id`'s to select people that are `Active`.

Probably better to use `JOIN`.